# Extracting tableColumns from using cube query inside fetch api

Tags: reactjs, next.js, kendo-ui, fetch, cube

```
import {
  Grid,
  GridCellProps,
  GridColumn,
  GridSortChangeEvent,
  GridToolbar,
} from "@progress/kendo-react-grid";
import { useCubeQuery } from "@cubejs-client/react";
```

```
const { resultSet, isLoading, error, progress } = useCubeQuery({
    dimensions: [
      "TenancySchedule.level",
      "TenancySchedule.SuiteNo",
      "TenancySchedule.LeaseType",
      "TenancySchedule.TenantName",
      "TenancySchedule.Initialarea",
      "TenancySchedule.LeaseStartDate", 
      "TenancySchedule.leasetermYears",
      "TenancySchedule.LeaseEndDate",
      "TenancySchedule.NetPassingRent",
      "TenancySchedule.NetPassingRentsqm",
      "TenancySchedule.Abatement",
      "TenancySchedule.Abatementsqm",
      "TenancySchedule.RevenueName",
      "TenancySchedule.Recoveries",
      "TenancySchedule.Recoveriessqm",
      "TenancySchedule.CommonAreaCleaning",
      "TenancySchedule.CommonAreaCleaningsqm",
      "TenancySchedule.CarSpaces",
      "TenancySchedule.ParkingRent",
      "TenancySchedule.ParkingRentsqm",
      "TenancySchedule.StorageOtherIncome",
    ],
    order: [
      ["TenancySchedule.SuiteNo", "asc"],
    ],
    limit: 5000,
    filters: [
      ...defaultFilters,
      ...(monthSelected != null ? monthFilters : []),
    ],
  });

resultSet.tableColumns()
```

resultSet.tableColumns() gives all metadata about the tableColumns.

How do I fetch the same data using the fetch api?

```
const url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL + '/genieglobal/v1/cubejs-api/v1/load';
```

```
 const getTenancyScheduleData = async(session:any)=> {
//passing encoded stringified cube query inside fetch
    const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(getTenancyScheduleQuery(assetCode,monthSelected)));
    try{
      const response = await fetch(`${url}?query=${encodedValue}&queryType=multi`, { 
        method: 'get',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+session?.accessToken, 
            'subscription-key': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY as string
        })})
      const dataResult = await response.json();
//How to fetch tableColumns from dataResult here


    }catch(error){
     console.log("catch")
    }
    
    }
```

How do I fetch tableColumns from dataResult obtained from fetch? TableColumns must have metadata for every column like the below:

dataIndex:"TenancySchedule.level"
format: undefined
key:"level"
locked:false
meta:undefined
shortTitle:"Level"
title:"Tenancy Schedule Level"
type: "string"

Answer (score 0):

I extracted the metadata from annotations in data from response.json()

```
const getTenancyScheduleData = async(session:any)=> {
const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(getTenancyScheduleQuery(assetCode,monthSelected)));
try{
  setIsLoading(true);
  const response = await fetch(`${url}?query=${encodedValue}&queryType=multi`, { 
    method: 'get',
    headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+session?.accessToken, 
        'subscription-key': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY as string
    })})
  **const data = await response.json();**
  let gridColumns :KendoTableColumn[] = []
  **if(data && data.results && data.results.length && data.results[0] && 
    data.results[0].annotation && data.results[0].annotation.dimensions){
  let metadata = data.results[0].annotation.dimensions;
  gridColumns = Object.keys(metadata).map((keyObj)=>{
    return {
      key:keyObj.split(".")[1],
      title:metadata[keyObj]['title'],
      shortTitle:metadata[keyObj]['shortTitle'],
      type:metadata[keyObj]['type'],
      dataIndex:keyObj,
      locked:false,
      format:"",
      meta:""
    }
  })
  setGridColumns(gridColumns)
  }**
  
  if(data && data.results && data.results.length && data.results[0] && data.results[0].data && data.results[0].data.length){
    const dataArr = data.results[0].data
    setGridData(dataArr);
  }
  setIsLoading(false);
}catch(error){
  setErrorCube(error as Error);
  setIsLoading(false);
}

}
```